# Attiny85 microcontroller programming without arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, avr, attiny85

I have decided to make a simple project so thinked about arduino but that seems very worthy so i decided to use attiny85 ic for my project,but i don't have arduino or avr to program it. Is there any way to program the below ic without arduino or avr?.

Comment: How about buying the [Digispark USB Development board](http://digistump.com/products/1), which uses an Attiny85 and can be programmed via USB?

Comment: I use a “USBasp” ISP programmer. Those are cheap, compatible with avrdude, and more convenient than an Arduino running the ArduinoISP firmware. Beware there are some Chinese “USBISP” programmers (note the spelling) that are _not_ compatible with avrdude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is there any way to program [a bare AVR microcontroller] without Arduino [hardware] or AVR [hardware programmer]?**

Programming a *bare* AVR microcontoller like the ATtiny85 *IC* needs either another Arduino board or an AVR programmer device.

---

#### Programmer $4-$7

Something like the Pololu AVR Programmer v2.1 can be bought for $7 and used with the free Arduino development software (IDE). I have used this to program an ATtiny85. This is what I would suggest, because a programmer is the most versatile solution.

[image: USBAPS] <sup>Even cheaper, a $4 USBASP</sup>

---

#### Arduino as ISP $4.50

I have used an old Arduino Duemilanove using the Arduino as ISP sketch as a programmer for an ATtiny85 but any Arduino with inbuilt USB and enough GPIO could be used. There are some low cost ATmega328P or ATmega32u4 based Arduino clones that would be suitable. A Nano v3 clone costs $4.50.

[image: Nano]

---

#### Development Board with USB $3

As others have commented, you can buy a "digispark" (just Google and click "shopping") for three or four dollars. This is essentially a breakout board with an ATtiny85, a USB connector and a soft-USB-capable bootloader pre-loaded onto the ATtiny85. You can program it with the Arduino IDE after using the IDE's board-manager to install Digistump's "core" definitions for the Digispark. It doesn't need another Arduino nor an AVR Programmer. I bought three on Amazon for $9 a month ago.

[image: three digisparks]

Since it *is* an Arduino-compatible development board, it doesn't really meet your requirement of "without Arduino" - but it might be the closest solution to what you have in mind.

---

Useful resources and inspiration:

- [ATtiny-Based Beginner's Kit](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?NMX)
- [Twelve PWM outputs from an ATtiny85](http://www.technoblogy.com/show?2H0K).

Yes, 12 LEDs individually controlled with just four resistors and four pins of an eight-pin ATtiny85 and and no other components!

I have no affiliation with the above site, I just think it is one anyone new to electronics with an ATtiny85  would find interesting.

Comment: Is there a way to *not* use Arduino IDE for development, but just a text editor and compile from command line?

Comment: @rustyx: that's a great question - I see the original question can also be interpreted that way. I'll add another answer for that interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there any way to program [a bare AVR microcontroller] without Arduino [IDE software] or AVR [software development toolkit]?**

I believe you can use

- A text editor of your choice to create and edit source code files.
- The GNU compiler [GCC-AVR](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcc+for+avr) to compile source code into machine-code.
- The [avrdude](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/) program to install the compiled code onto the microcontroller.

All these can be obtained at zero cost.

Comment: Thanks! I've also found [this](https://blog.podkalicki.com/how-to-compile-and-burn-the-code-to-avr-chip-on-linuxmacosxwindows/) and also [this](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/links.html) with links on how to debug and emulate AVR.